# WPF Creation versus Visual Studio Creation

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I created a form in WPF and it looked great. When I opened it in Visual Studio 2010, it look alot different than what I created.

Any ideas why this would happen? Should I ignore how it shows up in VS? This makes me wonder if either is how the user will actually see it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks again!
Eroc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio view of your WPF form is the designer view.  Designer views of WPF forms, or really any other design of a UI component, will often differ in dislpay vs. the actual running component.  Some of these differences are intentional to make design easier and some are just limitations of not having the WPF element actually running in a program (lack of certain runtime data bindings for example).

I wouldn't worry about it unless it starts looking incorrect when running.

Comment: Great, that's what I was wanting to know!